# How do I see all of the AWS IAM permissions on a user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

How do I see all of the AWS IAM permissions on a user/role/group? The stuff I find online only seem to show ways to list policies attached to these principals. I'm tasked with transplanting the permissions on an application's IAM user onto an ECS task role and I want to make sure I'm not forgetting about some S3 bucket policy or something.

Edit: ok here is more context.
I don't care if it's done using the command line or the UI? Why does that matter?
What I have tried is I went to the sections in IAM's page looking for helpful tools that would make it easy to find everything that needs to be changed to give a new role identical permissions and nothing showed anything about the SQS queue policies or the S3 bucket policies that apply to it. The only stuff there are things directly tied to the thing I am looking at: groups, policies, inline policies...

Comment: Do you wish to do this via the AWS management console, or programmatically? You could view the policies attached to the User and attached to any Group that the user is a member of. It is harder to parse a bucket policy to determine whether it applies to a particular user. What have you tried so far? Feel free to edit your question to add more details.

Comment: I second @JohnRotenstein’s comment... Need more detail and context to be able to provide a useful reply.

Comment: If it can be done in the console that would be good but I'm not shy of doing something programmatically. If you were tasked with doing this how would you do it? Is there an easy way to see everything that needs to be moved over? Am I barking up the wrong tree and should just try to look through the app and aws resources that share its name start copy/pasting what I find?